# Show DataGrid row details by clicking row header?

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

Normally row details are show when you click on a row. I want to disable this so that clicking a DataGrid row simply selects it but doesn't show the row details. I want the row details to be shown when a user clicks the row header. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop someone for getting the description when the row is clicked one adds this attribute to the grid:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgPrimary" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">
```

Then one adds two behaviors of type ChangePropertyAction, using expression blend is one of the easiest.

1. Mouse enter action
   [image: Properties Window in Blend for Mouse Enter]
2. Mouse leave action
   [image: Properties Window in Blend for Mouse Leave]

   Here is the original datagrid before the mouse moves over the headers
   [image]

Here is when I moved the mouse over my test project's datagrid dgPrimary. See how all the rows description opened up.
[image: Result datagrid when mouse moves over it]

Here is the code tacked on from blend to the datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgPrimary" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="20,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding New}" />

            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Original}"
                            Header="File Name Before"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding New}"
                            Header="File Name After"
                            IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="RowDetailsVisibilityMode">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode>Visible</DataGridRowDetailsVisibilityMode>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction x:Name="cpaLeave" PropertyName="RowDetailsVisibilityMode"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

And the code behind to load the datagrid

```
dgPrimary.ItemsSource = Directory.GetFiles( @"C:\" )
                                    .Select( ( nm, index ) => new
                                    {
                                        Original = System.IO.Path.GetFileName( nm ),
                                        New = string.Format( "{0}_{1}{2}", System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( nm ), index, System.IO.Path.GetExtension( nm ) )
                                    } );
```